# Update using loop taking too long

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm trying to update a table  inside a loop, and it is taking too long. Need help in how I can make this efficient?

A little background on the problem and the approach being used - 
I have the following table,

**Gift_Earned_Used**:

```
customer    earned_id    earned_day    earned_type    used_id    used_day    used_type

6832        1234         '01-JAN-19'   Free Pizza      null       null        null
6832        1771         '03-JAN-19'   Free Pizza      null       null        null
6506        1901         '07-JAN-19'   Free Coffee     null       null        null
```

The table currently has 33 million rows with nulls for `used_id`, `used_day` and `used_type`. The table contains all the customers that have earned a gift of any type (free pizza, free coffee, free bread) along with the respective transaction id (`earned_id`) and transaction day (`earned_day`).

The other table,

**Gift_Used**:

```
customer    used_id       used_day     used_type      ear_pos_earned_day

6832        1339         '31-DEC-18'   Free Pizza    '02-DEC-18'    
6832        1821         '03-JAN-19'   Free Pizza    '04-DEC-18'
6506        2454         '07-JAN-19'   Free Coffee   '08-JAN-19'
```

currently has 19 millions rows.

The problem is that when a customer use a gift, there is no way to tie that particular used gift to a gift earned. The `earned_id` and `used_id` are merely just transaction ids. And in an effort to do that, we are assuming first-in first-out approach.

That in this case assumes that the first used gift will tie to the first earned gift matching on customer and gift type. Also, there is a need to ensure that the used_day is not less than the earned_day (you simply cannot use a gift if you haven't already earned it). More specifically, the earned_day has to be between the `ear_pos_earned_day` and `used_day`.

To achieve that, I am looping over the **Gift_Used** table to update the nulls in the **Gift_Earned_Used** table where there is a match, such that my table **Gift_Earned_Used** after the update would look like:

```
customer    earned_id    earned_day    earned_type    used_id    used_day    used_type

6832        1234         '01-JAN-19'   Free Pizza      1821     '03-JAN-19'  Free Pizza
6832        1771         '03-JAN-19'   Free Pizza      null       null        null
6506        1901         '07-JAN-19'   Free Coffee     2454     '07-JAN-19'  Free Coffee
```

I took into consideration several use cases, and I am able to achieve what I want to through my code.

```sql
    DECLARE
     var_earned_id NUMBER;

    --looping through all the customers in the gift_used table 
    --and ordering it by used_day, used_id such that if there 
    --are two used gifts of the same type, the one with the lesser
    --transaction id gets assigned first
    BEGIN 
        FOR v_used IN 
        (
            SELECT /*+PARALLEL(8)*/
                 Customer           
                ,Used_Type          
                ,Used_Id            
                ,Used_Day   
                ,ear_pos_earned_day     
            FROM 
                gift_used
            ORDER BY 
                Customer,Used_Day,Used_Id
        )

        LOOP

            BEGIN

        --this is the part where i am getting the earned_id that matches
        --the criteria. If more than one earned_id matches the criteria 
        --, the top one is picked (one with lesser transaction id)

                SELECT Earned_Id INTO Var_Earned_Id FROM 
                (
                    SELECT Earned_Id FROM gift_earned_used 
                    WHERE 1=1
                        AND Customer = v_used.Customer 
                        AND Earned_Type = v_used.Used_Type 
                        AND Used_Id IS NULL 
                        AND Earned_Day BETWEEN v_used.ear_pos_earned_day AND v_used.used_day ORDER BY Earned_Day,Earned_Id
                )
                WHERE ROWNUM=1 
                    ;


        --for the earned_id picked above that matched the criteria
        --the values in the used_id and used_day are updated from loop              
                UPDATE /*+PARALLEL(8)*/ gift_earned_used u
                SET  u.used_id = v_used.Used_Id
                    ,u.used_day = v_used.used_day
                WHERE 1=1 
                    AND u.earned_id = Var_Earned_Id
                    ;

                EXCEPTION
                    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                        Var_Earned_Id := 0;
            END;

        END LOOP;

        COMMIT;

    END;
```

I am able to achieve the desired output as shown above. I tried several ways of doing it but could logically achieve this using loop construct only.

I tried it on small data sets, and it seems to work fine. But when I am doing it for the entire data set -- 33 million rows in gift_earned_used to be updated from gift_used (19 million rows) where there is a match - it just never stops. Takes too long.

I really need suggestions on how I can improve this, make it more efficient.

Comment: Okay so first of all: Your tables aren't normalised. Gift_Earned_Used has two ID's running but then you have the same ID (usedID) reused in the second table. That's a big nono. It's also unclear to me how exactly you determine if a gift was used at all. You have an earned ID but does the customer receive that ID in order to get his gift? I am not too familiar with plsql but in general: Looping on a database is not a good idea. If you can normalise your data you can handle the gifts as a single batch of data instead of running through every single row seperately.

Answer (score 1):

This addresses the original version of the question.

You can write a query to get the `used_id` for each earned by interleaving the rows and using window functions.

The idea is to assign a grouping using a cumulative count of earned/redeemed for each customer/type and then use that to assign the `used_id`.  This is tricky, because the cumulative count is a sum that ignores the current row for the redemption (it needs to be associated with the most recent earned value).

```
with eu as (
      select earned_id, customer, earned_date as date, earned_type as type, null as used_id, 1 as earned
      from gift_earned_used geu
      union all
      select null, customer, used_date as date, used_type as type, used_id, -1 as earned
      from gift_used geu
     ),
     eu2 as (
      select eu.*,
             (sum(earned) over (partition by customer, type 
                                order by date
                               ) -
              greatest(earned, 0) -- ignore current row for redemptions
             ) earned_grouping
      from eu
     )
select eu2.*
from (select eu2.*,
             lead(used_id ignore nulls) over (partition by customer, type, earned_grouping order by date) as new_used_id
      from eu2
     ) eu2
where used_id is null;  -- only select the earned rows
```

When you have verified that this works, you have two approaches:

1. Use `merge` to update the original table.
2. Join in the additional columns you want and replace the original table.

I would use the second method, because updating essentially every row in the table can be quite expensive.

Comment: In the part where you're using the lead function, did you mean to say eu2.* just above it? I am looking into this, and trying to get the sense of it on several use cases. An important thing I may have missed mentioning in my comment (the code reflects that) is that the **earned_day** should be between the **ear_pos_earned_day** and **earned_day** .

Comment: A great logic overall.